# Top Menu Navigation not displaying correctly in mobile

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, blogger

When viewing [my website on a mobile](https://www.latoyah.co.uk) the top menu is all stacked up, and does not appear the same as the desktop version (a horizontal, single-line menu) Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media query and specify the size of the device so that it fits the display automatically. Also you can use bootstrap libraries to resolve this problem.

You can refer to this link for more information.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: So what specifically do I need to do?